# add unrestricted html to ckeditor

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I am having issues with drupal and ckeditor. I would like to saev following code:

```
<div class="a2a_kit">
    <a class="a2a_button_facebook_like" data-action="recommend" data-href="http://example.com/" data-layout="box_count" data-width="55"></a>
</div>
```

However due to ckeditor's filters almost everything gets stripped. I tried various advices - turning off advanced content filter or adding `config.allowedContent = true;` inside custom javascript configuration window. Nothing what I tried works.
Thank you for any advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to:

/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Advanced (for Filter HTML)

/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full (for Full HTML)

Then under Advanced Content Filter, select disabled.

[image]

**If the above does not do it**, depending on which one you are using (filter or full html) You need to go to

/admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html

OR

/admin/config/content/formats/full_html

[image]

try unchecking the correct faulty and chopped off html box.

Comment: Hi, while these advices might worked in previous versions of ckeditor module/ckeditor/ckeditor library, none of it works with recent ckeditor module 7.x.-1.16 - tested on simplytest.me

Comment: @loparr I use 7.x.-1.16

Comment: I use ckeditor through [CKeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module, not through [Wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg)   which also allows you to use CKeditor. Not sure if this makes a difference.

Comment: hi, I just tested it more and understand it little bit more. Turning off content filter in 7.x.-1.16 and most recent ckeditor library will do the trick with data-href as well, while previous versions of ckeditor library do not listen to turning off filter completely, resulting in splitting data-href into data-="" and href.